# C# DateTime.Now comparing and synchronizing during shutdown PC

Tags: c#, shutdown

I have the situation given in the code which is part of my application, as below:

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  date2 = new DateTime();
  date2 =  DateTime.Now.AddHours(hoursToAdd).AddMinutes(minutesToAdd);

            date1 = new DateTime();
            date1 = DateTime.Now; 

            if(date1 == date2)
            {
                mySwitchOff();
            }
    }
```

I want to shutdown a PC at the  time which is given in that line:
***date2 = DateTime.Now.AddHours(hoursToAdd).AddMinutes(minutesToAdd);***
That line means that I want to add certain amount of hours and minutes to time when the button was clicked
and in the object date1 I try to set current time.
Then, I want to compare current time (date1) and previously set up time of shutdown the PC (date2) and call some "switching off" method.

My main problem is that in the date1 the DateTime.Now continously updates the time and adds set up hours and minutes to current hour no to hour when the button was clicked.

Can you give me an advise how can I do it to fix time when the button was clicked in one object and compare it with current time (which will be continously updating, given in another object) ?

Comment: Things are not clear. You want to shut down the PC in button click or you just want to schedule the shutdown to specific future date and time? Or you want to check if the current datetime is equal to previously scheduled datetime and shut down the PC if they are equal.

Comment: I want to schedule the shutdown. Firstly I set up time  and then I click that button which executes code as above. And I have that issue which I described

Comment: Which code sets up time? In the button click you are using `DateTime.Now` and adding hours and minutes to it and then comparing it to the `DateTime.Now`. They will not be the same at all. The computer will never shutdown in button click code. You need to store the shutdown time to somewhere and in the button click you should retrieve that time and compare it with current datetime and if they match you shutdown the PC.

Comment: I'm setting up shutdown time in another method. And I add it to DateTime.Now after click that button which code I posted.
Ok, so, I will try to add that hours and minutes to DateTime.Now immediately after setting up it in the same method. Not just in the button click